# PHPExcel taking an extremely long time to read Excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel 1.7.8, PHP 5.4.14, Windows 7, and an Excel 2007 spreadsheet. The spreadsheet consists of 750 rows, columns A through BW, and is about 600KB in size. This is my code for opening the spreadsheet--pretty standard:

```
//Include PHPExcel_IOFactory
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
include 'PHPExcel.php';

$inputFileName = 'C:\xls\lspimport\GetLSP1.xlsx';

//  Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

//set active worksheet
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexbyName('Sheet1');

$j = 0;

for($i = 2; $i < 3; $i++)
{
...
}
```

In the end, I eventually want to loop through each row in the spreadsheet, but for the time being while I perfect the script, I'm only looping through one row. The problem is, it takes 30 minutes for this script to execute. I `echo`'d messages after each section of code so I could see what was being processed and when, and my script basically waits for 30 minutes at this part:

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

Have a configured something incorrectly? I can't figure out why it takes 30 minutes to load the spreadsheet. I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: what do you have in this spreadsheet? images?

Comment: No, only text and numerical data.

Comment: So overall about 750x75 cells.... have you verified that the 30 minutes is in the reader? or in looping through the cells? As the author of PHPExcel, I'm very concerned that any spreadsheet would take that long to load, I've spent a lot of time over the last two years working on improving both speed and memory usage: I've never come across anything that takes that long before, and I run my own performance tests against spreadsheets several times the size of yours. If possible, can you provide a sample (client confidentiality permitting) on the codeplex site for me to run some of my own tests.

Comment: Want me to just upload it to Issues?

Comment: That's the best place to upload it

Answer (score 5):

PHPExcel has a problem with identifying where the end of your excel file is. Or rather, Excel has a hard time knowing where the end of itself is. If you touch a cell at A:1000000 it thinks it needs to read that far.

I have done 2 things in the past to fix this:

1) Cut and past the data you need into new excel file.
2) Specify the exact dimensions you want to read.

**Edit How to do option 2**

```
public function readExcelDataToArray($excelFilePath, $maxRowNumber=-1, $maxColumnNumber=-1)
{
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($excelFilePath);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    //Get last row and column that have data
    if ($maxRowNumber == -1){
    $lastRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestDataRow();
    } else {
        $lastRow = $maxRowNumber;
    }

    if ($maxColumnNumber == -1){
        $lastCol = $objWorksheet->getHighestDataColumn();
        //Change Column letter to column number
        $lastCol = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($lastCol);      
    } else {
        $lastCol = $maxColumnNumber;
    }   

    //Get Data Array
    $dataArray = array();

    for ($currentRow = 1; $currentRow <= $lastRow; $currentRow++){
        for ($currentCol = 0; $currentCol <= $lastCol; $currentCol++){
            $dataArray[$currentRow][$currentCol] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($currentCol,, $currentRow)->getValue();
        }
    }
    return $dataArray;
}
```

Unfortunately these solutions aren't very dynamic.

Note that a modern excel file is really just a zip with an xlsx extension. I have written extensions to PHPExcel that unzip them, and modify certain xml files to get the kinds of behaviors I want.

A third suggestion for you would be to monitor the contents of each row and stop when you get an empty one.

Comment: How do I do option 2 exactly? What function do I use?

Comment: I tried your Option 1, and it seems to be taking just as long. :(

Comment: Actually, you're wrong... if a cell exists, then PHPExcel will read it, if a cell doesn't exist then there's nothing for PHPExcel to read. If you touch cells A1 and A10000, that's still only 2 cells to read, so that won't make reading slow.

Comment: Forgive me. I don't know exactly what might causes Excel to think it has data in a large cell range but it does. That is the value that PHPExcel reads with the method `getHighestColumn()` I think. It has been a while I just know that I made this method to fix the problem I was having which sounds identical.

Comment: getHighestColumn()/getHighestRows() doesn't mean that all the columns and rows up to that point have to be loaded as well, especially if they don't exist... and may include columns/rows that contain only styling information, images, etc rather than data. getHighestDataRow()/getHighestDataColumn() may be useful alternatives because they're based on cell content, though they have to be calculated by PHPExcel itself rather than retrieved from the file.

Comment: If you do end up identifying A10000 as the highest cell, when there's no data in any of the earlier rows, than that will affect looping through the data once it's loaded; but should increase the load time at all

Comment: @MarkBaker Those are good alternative methods and you make a good distinction. I am going to update my methods to use those and edit my post.

Comment: @km6zla actually is right. I did some debugging and found out that PHPExcel, in a 5 seconds time limit, reached the `C32822` cell, which is totally wrong since my `xlsx` file has only 1027 rows.
If you also want to debug this, uncommented this portion of code: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php#L825


PS: PHPExcel is not longer maintaned. Use instead https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Answer (score 2):

**Resolved (for me) - see note at bottom of this post**

I'm trying to use pretty much identical code on a dedicated quad core server with 16GB of RAM, also running similar versions - PHPExcel 1.7.9 and PHP 5.4.16

Just creating an empty reader takes 50 seconds!

```
// $inputFileType is 'Excel5';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
```

Loading the spreadsheet (1 sheet, 2000 rows, 25 columns) I want to process (readonly) then takes 1802 seconds.

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

Of the various types of reader I consistently get timings for instantiation as shown below

```
foreach(array(
  'Excel2007',     // 350 seconds
  'Excel5',        //  50 seconds
  'Excel2003XML',  //  50 seconds
  'OOCalc',        //  50 seconds
  'SYLK',          //  50 seconds
  'Gnumeric',      //  50 seconds
  'HTML',          // 250 seconds
  'CSV'            //  50 seconds
  ) as $inputFileType) {
  $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
}
```

Peak memory usage was about 8MB... far less than the 250MB the script has available to it.

My suspicion WAS that `PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType)` was calling something within a loop that's extremely slow under PHP 5.4.x ?

**However** the excessive time was due to how PHPExcel names its class names and corresponding file structure. It has an autoloader that converts class names such as *PHPExcel_abc_def* into *PHPExcel/abc/def.php* for the require statement.  Although we had PHPExcel's class directory defined in our include path, our own (already defined) autoloader couldn't handle the manipulation from class name to file name required (it was looking for *PHPExcel_abc_def.php*).  When a class file cannot be included, our autoloader will loop 5 times with a 10 second delay to see if the file is being updated and so might become available.  So for every PHPExcel class that needed to be loaded we were introducing a delay of 50 seconds before hitting PHPExcel's own autoloader which required the file in fine.

Now that I've got that resolved PHPExcel is proving to be truly awesome.

Comment: How did you resolve this class reading issues please? I have the same problem and I can't get over it.

Comment: @PeterKrejci The PHPExcel autoloader was still working for me, it just too 5 x 10 seconds before it was getting called due to the code in our own autoloader which was called first.  So every time a PHPExcel class needed loading, it took 50 seconds.  Modifying our own autoloader to avoid this 50 second wait fixed things for us.  We've since moved on to using Composer to load PHPExcel, which also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the latest version of PHPExcel (1.8.1) in a Symfony project, and I also ran into time delays when using the $objReader->load($file) method. The time delays were not due to an autoloader, but to the load method itself. This method actually reads every cell in every worksheet. And since my data worksheet was 30 columns wide by 5000 rows, it took about 90 seconds to read all this information on my ancient work computer.

I assumed that the real loading/reading of cell values would occur on the fly as I requested them, but it looks like short of a pretty major re-write of the PHPExcel code, there's no real way around this initial load time delay.

Comment: You are right, that's how PHPExcel works. A spreadsheet contains a lot of dynamic information, so PHPExcel's strategy is to load everything in memory first, so that the reading part itself is pretty fast. This has a pretty big drawback: it's slow and requires a lot of memory. There are ways to improve this but the current strategy won't work with big files... Another way to do this is by using streams: nothing is preloaded and only the read row is kept in memory (along with some metadata. If you are interested, this is how [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) was implemented :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know your file is a pretty plain excel file, you can do manual reading. A .xslx file is just a zip archive with the spreadsheet values and structure stored into xml files. This script took me from the 60 seconds used on PHPExcel down to 0.18 seconds.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('path_to/file.xlsx');
$sheet_xml = simplexml_load_string($zip->getFromName('xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml'));
$sheet_array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);
$values = simplexml_load_string($zip->getFromName('xl/sharedStrings.xml'));
$values_array = json_decode(json_encode($values), true);

$end_result = array();
if ($sheet_array['sheetData']) {
    foreach ($sheet_array['sheetData']['row'] as $r => $row) {
        $end_result[$r] = array();
        foreach ($row['c'] as $c => $cell) {
            if (isset($cell['@attributes']['t'])) {
                if ($cell['@attributes']['t'] == 's') {
                    $end_result[$r][] = $values_array['si'][$cell['v']]['t'];
                } else if ($cell['@attributes']['t'] == 'e') {
                    $end_result[$r][] = '';
                }
            } else {
                $end_result[$r][] = $cell['v'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C2
        )
)
```

This is error prone and not optimized, but it works and illustrates the basic idea. If you know your file, then you can make reading very fast. If you allow users to input the files, then you should maybe avoid it - or at least do the neccessary checks.