# PHPExcel takes long time to load xls, fine with xlsx

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xls, xlsx

Good day.
I have xls file that looks like this:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| ID | PRICE | STATUS |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 |  1000 |      1 |
|  2 |  1000 |      3 |
|  4 |  1324 |      5 |
|  8 |  3141 |      1 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

As you can see there is not too much rows and cols. But when i try to save it like XLS file and then load to PHPExcel like this:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('1.xls');
```

It takes eternity to load, and Server CPU and RAM usage grows like magic tree. But when i try to do the same stuff with XLSX it works like LeBron James. Like this:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('1.xlsx');
```

PHP extensions: zip, xml, gd, xmlreader, xmlwriter, xmlrpc are installed and works. PHP ver 5.6.12 FastCGI.

Comment: May be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742647/phpexcel-taking-an-extremely-long-time-to-read-excel-file

Comment: Do you have more than one sheet in your file? If other sheets contain a lot of data, loading the entire file will take a long time